# How to delete a non-empty S3 bucket using AWS SDK for Go v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I'm using AWS sdk v2

and I need to delete a bucket that had objects

what's the best way to do so? is there something to force delete? or that deleted all the objects inside a bucket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AWS documentation [Deleting a bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/delete-bucket.html) describes how to delete a bucket that has objects. The documentation also provides an SDK example (written in Java, but mainly serves as a guideline) that performs the following steps:

- Delete all objects
- Delete all object versions (for versioned buckets)
- Finally delete bucket

There is no "force delete" option for non-empty buckets. You would need to implement the above steps.

The following sample code shows how to completely delete a non-empty bucket:

```
func main() {
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRegion("us-east-1"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to load config: %v", err)
    }

    bucket := aws.String("your-bucket-name")
    client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    deleteObject := func(bucket, key, versionId *string) {
        log.Printf("Object: %s/%s\n", *key, aws.ToString(versionId))
        _, err := client.DeleteObject(context.TODO(), &s3.DeleteObjectInput{
            Bucket:    bucket,
            Key:       key,
            VersionId: versionId,
        })
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to delete object: %v", err)
        }
    }

    in := &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{Bucket: bucket}
    for {
        out, err := client.ListObjectsV2(context.TODO(), in)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to list objects: %v", err)
        }

        for _, item := range out.Contents {
            deleteObject(bucket, item.Key, nil)
        }

        if out.IsTruncated {
            in.ContinuationToken = out.ContinuationToken
        } else {
            break
        }
    }

    inVer := &s3.ListObjectVersionsInput{Bucket: bucket}
    for {
        out, err := client.ListObjectVersions(context.TODO(), inVer)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to list version objects: %v", err)
        }

        for _, item := range out.DeleteMarkers {
            deleteObject(bucket, item.Key, item.VersionId)
        }

        for _, item := range out.Versions {
            deleteObject(bucket, item.Key, item.VersionId)
        }

        if out.IsTruncated {
            inVer.VersionIdMarker = out.NextVersionIdMarker
            inVer.KeyMarker = out.NextKeyMarker
        } else {
            break
        }
    }

    _, err = client.DeleteBucket(context.TODO(), &s3.DeleteBucketInput{Bucket: bucket})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to delete bucket: %v", err)
    }
}
```

You should probably optimize this further and use `DeleteObjects` for batch calls in order to reduce request overhead.